# Linking two html inputs and insert into database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am having difficulty inserting two concatenated inputs into the database. It seems that the connection is good but the data does not get inserted into the db.
Could someone please assist?

The code is as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
             (function($){
                 $(document).ready( function(){

                    $('#country').change( function(e){
                         //on change event 
                        $('input[name="s_dialcode"]').val($(this).find('option:selected').data('co'));  
                    });

                }); //make sure all html is loaded before running
             })(jQuery);  //assign jQuery to the $


            function validate(evt) {
      var theEvent = evt || window.event;
      var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
      key = String.fromCharCode( key );
      var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
      if( !regex.test(key) ) {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
      }
    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <select id="country" name="s_country">
        <option data-co="" value="">Which country are from?</option>
        <option data-co="+27" value="ZA">South Africa</option>
        <option data-co="+376" value="AD">Andorra</option>
        <option data-co="+971" value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
    </select>


    <?php 
    $countryArray = array(
        'AD'=>array('name'=>'ANDORRA','code'=>'376'),
        'AE'=>array('name'=>'UNITED ARAB EMIRATES','code'=>'971'),
        'ZA'=>array('name'=>'SOUTH AFRICA','code'=>'27')
    );
    ?>

    <form action="" method="_POST">

    <input type="text" name="s_dialcode" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="">
    <input type="text" onkeypress='validate(event)' name="s_mobilenumber" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="What is your Mobile Number?">
    <input type="submit" name="s_submit" value="Next"><br/>
    <a href="">Skip</a>

    </form>

    </body>


    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){

        $('form').on('submit', (function(e){

          $('.s_submit').prop('disabled', true);
          $('.overlay-2').show();
          var mobilenumber = $('.s_mobilenumber').val();
          $.ajax({
            url: DIR+"/ajaxify/ajax_requests/register_requests.php",
            method: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: {
              mobilenumber: mobilenumber
            },
          });
        }));

      });


    <?php

        require_once '../config/class/dbconfig.php';
        $usermobile = $_POST['dialcode'].$_POST['mobilenumber'];
     class login_class{
       public function REGISTER($usermobile){

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO userbio(mobilenumber)");
            }

      }//Ends here
    }
    ?>
</html>
```

I simply need the `usermobile` variable to concatenate the `dialcode` and the `mobilenumber` and insert `usermobile` into the DB. I am having a lot of problems getting this right. Also, I am using PDO.

I would appreciate any help or feedback on the above code.

Comment: I don't see you calling the `REGISTER` method.

Comment: .. and you don't do anything with the query you've prepared in REGISTER, and the SQL statement isn't valid (.. or complete).

Comment: This is the second page after completion of the signup form. Shouldn't I just continue from the signup with Register function?

Comment: I'm voting this as a typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO userbio(mobilenumber) values(?)");
        $query->execute($mobilenumber);
  }
```

Let's Try it...

Comment: would the values in this case be :mobilenumber? or would it be :usermobile?

Comment: It should be your variable which you use in your program to store the phone number... I used $mobilenumber as a placeholder of your variable..

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate an object of that class and call the REGISTER function

```
$login = new login_class();
$login->REGISTER($usermobile);
```

Your sql adapter code is incomplete also, after preparing you have to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

// insert one row
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();
```

That is the relevant part from the PHP PDO documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Your query appears to be missing the values clause.

$query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO userbio(mobilenumber) values (?)");

Also I am assuming you executed this query:

$query->execute($mobilenumber);

Are you using PDO or mysqli? That would determine the exact syntax of the insert lines.

Comment: Ah. I am using PDO

Comment: you posted 3 answers already, you need to delete 2 of them; this is one of them